# how to add widgets to the checkout page in MAGENTO

Tags: magento, widget, checkout

Can i know how to add widgets to check out page in Magento. I have gone through many tutorials and googled but dint understand . I want to add some browse buttons and text boxes (html content :) ) to the checkout page. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to declare your widget or Static Block instance in your checkout.xml to have it display there.

Check this page to understand the concept of widgets. http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/introducing-magento-widgets/

If you didn't already, I suggest you go through the designer's guide which will explain to you the basic structure of Magento and the XML layout concepts.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide